# How to group and sort on multiple fields?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a stream of objects that is grouped by two fields. I would like to sort results on the two fields (first by field1, then by field2) :

```
for(var group : data
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x ->
        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(x.field1, x.field2)))
   .entrySet()
   .stream()
   .sorted(...) //not sure what to put here
   .toList()) {
}
```

What I tried so far (it does not compile) :

```
.sorted(Comparator
   .comparing(x -> x.getKey().getKey())
   .thenComparing(x -> x.getKey().getValue()))
```

And :

```
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Map.EntrycomparingByKey()
                    .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())))
```

Comment: It helps to show input and expected output.  So show your Object class and and a list of those objects to be grouped and then sorted.   Please show data structures properly populated with sample data (I.e. no JSON like constructs, etc).  And remember, maps may not hold duplicate keys so you need to explain how the values for duplicate keys will be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to achieve what I wanted this way :

```
data
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> 
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x.field1, x.field2))) 
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Map.Entry.<String,String>comparingByKey()
                                   .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())))
```

The trick is to use `SimpleEntry<>` instead of `SimpleEntry` (so it stay strongly typed) and to specify the types of the fields that need to be sorted : `Map.Entry.<String, String>` instead of `Map.Entry`. I am not sure why Java is able to infer the types for the first `Map.Entry.comparingByKey()` call (just after the `sorted()` call) and not the second one.

For complex cases, the solution suggested by *mattdf* is better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to edit the previous entry by Partha Sarathi.  There's no need to create an intermediate collection.  Just compare the two fields in the comparator.  Since it's already a stream I don't see the need to `collect` or `stream` before sorting:

```
  data
  .sorted((e1,e2)->{
      var comp1 = e1.field1.compareTo(e2.field1)
      if(comp1 == 0){
          return e1.field2.compareTo(e2.field2);
      }
      return comp1;
  })
 .toList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply define a `comparator` with your sorting logic. Here is a sample code. [**I have assumed that both `field1` and `field2` are `String` type, and applied `compareTo` method. You can apply your preferred comparing technique based on the data type.**]

```
data
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x ->
      new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(x.field1, x.field2)))
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .sorted((e1,e2)->{
      var a = e1.getKey();
      var b = e2.getKey();
     
      int keyCompare = a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
      if(keyCompare == 0){
          return a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());
      }
      return keyCompare;
  })
  .toList();
```

Now, you can declare your `comparator` class with the same logic and pass the object inside the `sorted` method too. That might give a better readability.

Comment: You are evaluating `compareTo(b.getKey())` more often than necessary, which may be a performance penalty.